# cordova-plugin-iosrtc not work with sip.js 0.11 on movile ionic js webrtc app

Tags: ionic-framework, webrtc, cordova-plugins, freeswitch

I am developing a webrtc call/videocall app bases on Ionic/AngularJS technologies. The app works with sip.js for call actions over PBX server. For IOS integration with WebRtc, app works with cordova-plugin-iosrtc.  When I try connect with PBX to call or received call, app throws errors on two possible use mode of cordova-plugin-iosrtc with sip.js

A) When I try to use cordova-plugin-iosrtc working on peer connection iOS plugin mode ....

telephoneService.js (Angular JS)

```
var pc = new cordova.plugins.iosrtc.RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: []
});

cordova.plugins.iosrtc.getUserMedia(
  // constraints
  { audio: true, video: true },
  // success callback
  function (stream) {
    console.log('got local MediaStream: ', stream);
    pc.addStream(stream);
  },
  // failure callback
  function (error) {
    console.error('getUserMedia failed: ', error);
  }
);

var sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions = {

                constraints: {
                    audio: audioId,
                    video: videoId
                },


                media: {
                    local: {
                      audio: document.getElementById('localAudio')
                    },
                    remote: {
                      audio: document.getElementById('remoteAudio')
                    }
                },


            extraHeaders: extraHeaders

            }

}

userAgent.invite('sipusertocall', sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions);
```

receive the next error:

```
undefined is not a object evaluating 'environment.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia' (sip.js lib)
```

B)

```
cordova.plugins.iosrtc.registerGlobals(); use iosrtc plugin with webrtc native api (navigator.mediaDevice.getUserMedia(), ....)

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
     function (stream) {
        console.log('got local MediaStream: ', stream);

        window.stream = stream;
      },
      // failure callback
      function (error) {
        console.error('getUserMedia failed: ', error);
      }
    )

    var sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions = {

                    constraints: {
                        audio: audioId,
                        video: videoId
                    },


                    media: {
                        local: {
                          audio: document.getElementById('localAudio')
                        },
                        remote: {
                          audio: document.getElementById('remoteAudio')
                        }
                    },


                extraHeaders: extraHeaders

            }

    userAgent.invite('sipusertocall', sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions);

App receive from sip.js next error from PBX: Failed:WebRTC Error
```

Client show next error at same time:

> setLocalDescription() must be called with a RTCSessionDescription instance as first argument

Answer (score 0):

So the newer SIP.js is actually passing in an instance of RTCSessionDescriptionInit which although has a similar structure: { sdp: ..., type: ... } to an RTCSessionDescription init is not accepted by the cordova iosrtc implementation.

I have created a fix for this in the form of a custom SDH for SIP.js (as I encountered the exact same issue). My custom SDH converts the object to a new RTCSessionDescription(...) just before it gets passed in to getLocationDescription and setRemoteDescription.

Link to SDH plugin:
https://github.com/iotum/cordova-ios-session-description-handler

Hope this helps!
Wes

Comment: i looked at the github link shared but confused how to use it npm install I understand but what i am confused about is does it become part of cordova or it needs to be installed with sip.js as per https://github.com/onsip/SIP.js/blob/master/docs/README.md ?